# How can i write into specific column and read specific column in java(Excel)?

Tags: java, android, excel, android-studio, barcode

So i'm writing an application, but im struggled now. In this application you can scan the Barcode and when it scanned then a customdialog will pop up. There is a Texview which will show the scanned barcode product name(Datas are in excel "BARCODE" "PRODUCTNAME"). On the dialog there is a Edittext where the user can enter the product quantity and finally there is button which is execute the datas into the selected excel file("BARCODE" "PRODUCTNAME" "QUANTITY").

My questions are : 1. How can i read all cell only in the first columns("A") from excel file?
                   2. How can i write into specified column "C" next empty cell (Still into an excel file)?

Scanner Codes

```
public class ScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "";
private ZXingScannerView zXingScannerView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //set the main content layout of the Activity
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_barcode_scanner);

    ViewGroup contentFrame = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    zXingScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
    contentFrame.addView(zXingScannerView);

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    zXingScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    zXingScannerView.startCamera();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    zXingScannerView.stopCamera();
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
    zXingScannerView.stopCamera();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Contents = " + rawResult.getText() +
            ", Format = " + rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.result_dialog, viewGroup, false);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(dialogView);
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    Objects.requireNonNull(dialog.getWindow()).setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
    TextView myAwesomeTextView = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.resultname);
    myAwesomeTextView.setText(rawResult.getText());
    dialog.show();

    Button resultbutton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.resultbutton);
    resultbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            zXingScannerView.startCamera();
        }
    });

    // Note:
    // * Wait 2 seconds to resume the preview.
    // * On older devices continuously stopping and resuming camera preview can result in freezing the app.
    // * I don't know why this is the case but I don't have the time to figure out.
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            zXingScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(ScanActivity.this);
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

}

Reader Code

```
public class ReadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "";
public static String cellValue;
public static AssetManager assetManager;
public static HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook;
public static HSSFSheet mySheet;
public static HSSFRow myRow;

public void LoadingDatas(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    assetManager = getAssets();
    inputStream = (FileInputStream) assetManager.open(SecondActivity.filePath);
    myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();
    while (rowIter.hasNext()) {
        myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
        while (cellIter.hasNext()) {

            HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();

            if (myCell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                cellValue = myCell.getStringCellValue();
            } else {
                cellValue = String.valueOf(myCell.getNumericCellValue());
            }

            Log.v(LOG_TAG, cellValue);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Writer code

```
public class WriteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "";
public static String cellValue;
public static AssetManager assetManager;
public static HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook;
public static HSSFSheet mySheet;
public static HSSFRow myRow;
public static int rowstart;
public static int rowend;

public void WritingDatas(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    assetManager = getAssets();
    inputStream = (FileInputStream) assetManager.open(SecondActivity.filePath);
    myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

    for (int rowNum = rowstart; rowNum < rowend; rowNum++) {
        Row r = mySheet.getRow(rowNum);
        if (r == null) {
            continue;
        }

        int lastColumn = Math.max(r.getLastCellNum(), 0);

        for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
            Cell c = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
            if (c == null) {

            } else {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Is it a requirement for your project that you are using an actual Excel file (.xlss)? If all you're trying to do is essentially use Excel as a database then you would be better off using a .csv format that you can open in Excel if you require (you'd actually be better off using an actual database, although that might not be a satisfying answer).

There are numerous guides to writing between Java and CSV, here is one: https://www.baeldung.com/java-csv

If you are adamant that you need to use Excel then the following library exists that will simply your IO http://jxls.sourceforge.net/getting_started.html